# Asking for user info anonymously Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In an old application some people in my company were able to get info from Microsoft Graph without signing users in. I've tried to replicate this but I get unauthorized when trying to fetch users. I think the graph might have changed, or I'm doing something wrong in Azure when I register my app.

So in the Azure portal I have registered an application (web app), and granted it permissions to Azure ad and Microsoft graph to read all users full profiles.

Then I do a request

```
var client = new RestClient(string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/token", _tenant));

var request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.POST;

request.AddParameter("tenant", _tenant);
request.AddParameter("client_id", _clientId);
request.AddParameter("client_secret", _secret);
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
request.AddParameter("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com");
request.AddParameter("scope", "Directory.Read.All");
```

I added the last row (scope) while testing. I still got a token without this but the result is same with or without it.

After I get a token I save it and do this request:

```
var testClient = new RestClient(string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{0}", "test@test.onmicrosoft.com")); //I use a real user here in my code ofc.
testRequest = new RestRequest();
testRequest.Method = Method.GET;
testRequest.AddParameter("Authorization", _token.Token);
var testResponse = testClient.Execute(testRequest);
```

However now I get an error saying unauthorized, Bearer access token is empty.
The errors point me to signing users in and doing the request, however I do not want to sign a user in. As far as I know this was possible before. Have Microsoft changed it to not allow anonymous requests?

If so, is it possible to not redirecting the user to a consent-page? The users are already signed in via Owin. However users may have different access and I want this app to be able to access everything from the azure ad, regardless of which user is logged in. How is the correct way of doing this nowadays?

Or am I just missing something obvious? The app has been given access to azure and Microsoft graph and an admin has granted permissions for the app.

**Edit**: just to clarify, I tried both "Authorization", "bearer " + _token.Token, and just _token.Token as in the snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's still possible to make requests to Graph without a user present using [application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds). You will need to have the tenant admin consent and approve your application.

**Edit / answer:** Adding the 'Authorization' as a header instead of a parameter did the trick. It works both with 'bearer *token*' and just '*token*'

Comment: I should have clarified that I have tried both. I tried "bearer *token*" and just token. I'll edit to make it clear. What permissions do i need? I granted permissions (and gave consent as an admin) to read all users profiles, full and basic. What more do I need?

Comment: I think those scopes will suffice. Have you tried sending the token as an HTTP header vs. serialized a parameter?

Comment: It did the trick, i edited your answer and added it there. Thanks a lot!